# convert(all type) file into bytes angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, file, controller, binary

I am creating a web app in which i need to convert the uploaded file into binary format and store it into the database

this is how i have done this in c#

```
Stream fs = fempupload.PostedFile.InputStream;

BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
```

now i want to do the same with angularjs

```
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color:whitesmoke;">
         <label>Upload Your Photo</label>
         <input type="file" ng-model="mdfile" class="form-control"  custom-file-input />
   </div>
```

from here i am uploading my data

```
<a href="#" ng-click="savefunction()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" ng-animate="'btn'"><i></i>Save</a>
```

this is my save button

can anybody help me to convert the data into binary format from my controller

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
  <br>
  <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
  <p>{{data}}</p>
</div>
```

suppose it is your html code then write following code into your controller that will give you the file format in binary format

```
    $scope.data = 'none';
    $scope.add = function(){
      var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
          r = new FileReader();
      r.onloadend = function(e){
        $scope.data = e.target.result;
      }
      r.readAsBinaryString(f);
```

so on sending to the server time you need to add base 64 string like that

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,binary format of file
```

Hope it will help you . for any question or any updation in my code please write in comment section ..

Comment: Failed to execute 'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': The object is already busy reading Blobs.

this is what I am getting

Comment: if after this also your problem is not resolve then send your code fiddle or plunker . so that i can identify actual problem ..thanks

Comment: CÉ{´Ã!¥í`ÊNßbr·Å5iH²Õþ{Óví¬ìÁ·{ï9ù¸9I¶øepcE¥rG XÅÚåèu³ ïQ`U5`Ñ¢¸½ÉNYeàÙT`OR6e:G{çt±e{ÔFÞ¡¼¸­¤Î·f5eº2ÇåÔQÜC=ÑÉÙÔGSvÎ0 A9ã(Æ¯#íÕòË)k4\µâèþ¶b4ÖuÕ³Îê÷ñûúé¥»j(TTd¥N¸_J_Ùãç0×ÇÆ×Ìu)uê0i³>@SW[nÒyËÐÎ¿`O¼»¤Ö­ýnðeS,÷ô$TÇù£´f'Ñ~â®smvN¶


this is how the data is coming,,

is it a right way?

Comment: my data is coming in this format, it is working fine or i need to change the code???

Comment: so just include base 64 string with data and send back to the server